High latency observed for the initial data transfer
Recently, I measured latency between a subscriber node and a publisher node to find that the first message that gets delivered has high latency; subsequent ones are less.
My wild guess of the reason is as follows,

Discovery Process: The initial discovery process where nodes exchange information about available topics and establish connections can introduce latency.

Resource Allocation: The first message transmission triggers the allocation of various resources, such as memory buffers, data structures, and communication channels, which can add overhead.


How do I confirm that its the case?
Can anyone point me out to any docs/code which I was not able to find one that supports my assumption?
Is there a way to configure fastdds config in the xml?
Thanks in advance

how high is that initial latency?

0.1 millisecond.. although the number is small and negligible, I curious to learn why that happens since I was not able to find docs pertaining to it
